# Can I install a widget on Monterrey?

Tags: dashboard-widget

I have an old .wdgt that I came across.

I'm wondering if there's a way to install it in Monterrey or am I out of luck?

Answer (score -4):

This might help:

[How to Enable Dashboard Features in macOS Catalina](https://beebom.com/enable-dashboard-features-macos-catalina/)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant. Also, while doing so, please point how *how* the information from the linked article helps to run a .wdgt file on Monterey.